# OAuth 2.0 - calling server api on Iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, oauth, webserver

I want to start using OAuth to call my web server apis.
Preferably I want to use the new OAuth 2.0

Since I'm new to this stuff, I'm not sure exactly what I'm gonna need.
I looked around and most of the examples are about twitter, however I'm gonna need the OAuth to call my own server api.

Is there a recommended library for it ?
I saw [google](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) one , is that gonna do the job or there's others ?

Second, I'm making my url request using TTURLRequest , is there a way to provide this object with the token ? (I'm not the server guy so bear with my lack of knowledge here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [oauthconsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/), which is based on the project you linked to, oauth. There's a good guide to get you started [here](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer), and it discusses using request and access tokens as well.

Comment: It's just me or that it seems more complicated then google's implementation ?

Comment: I think it's the same thing, just adding Obj-C bindings. You could also try MPOAuthConnection: http://code.google.com/p/mpoauthconnection/ it looks to be more high level.

Comment: Indeed looks much simpler, Might try to use that. do you have any idea how to use the token with TTURLRequest ?

Comment: No sorry, I'm not familiar with TTURLRequest.